# Controlling where Docker starts incremental builds (use case: git clone inside Dockerfile)

Tags: git, docker

From what I understand, `docker build` is smart about building images incrementally, i.e. compiling only those layers where changes occured. For instance, if the source file for a `COPY` statement in `Dockerfile` changed, and everything else stayed the same, Docker will only execute statements starting from that `COPY` and otherwise reuse previously compiled layers.

I have a scenario where I `RUN git clone` inside the Docker image at build time and would like for `docker build` to start its incremental build from that statement (if any source file changed).

I guess I could enforce this by placing a `COPY dummy /` just before that statement and tell Docker about changes to source files with `touch dummy`. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to solve this by following @JHarris' [lead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39067569/1789384). My Dockerfile now looks like this:

```
FROM ...
ARG ...
ENV ...

# run lengthy installs
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y ...

# ...

ARG HEAD

RUN TMP_DIR=$(mktemp -d) && \
  cd $TMP_DIR && \
  git clone $GIT_REPOSITORY && \
# compile source code
# install from compile
  cd $TMP_DIR && \
  rm -fr $TMP_DIR

# ...
```

And I start the build process with:

```
docker build --build-arg HEAD=$(git ls-remote $GIT_REPOSITORY refs/heads/master | \
                                cut -f1) .
```

In effect, `HEAD` receives a new (hash) value whenever a new push to `$GIT_REPOSITORY` has occured. If that happens, it starts an "incremental" build starting from the line after `ARG HEAD`. The key factoid was this sentence from the [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) (section `ARG`, subsection *Impact on build caching*):

> If a Dockerfile defines an ARG variable whose value is different from
>   a previous build, then a “cache miss” occurs upon its first usage, not
>   its definition. In particular, all RUN instructions following an ARG
>   instruction use the ARG variable implicitly (as an environment
>   variable), thus can cause a cache miss.

This indicates that `ARG HEAD` must be placed as far down in `Dockerfile` as possible. Even though it is a definition, and could be placed further up by itself, all `RUN` statements following it already count as uses of `HEAD`. So in my example it is important to place it after the `RUN apt-get`s for lengthy installs, in particular.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `ARG` instruction in Dockerfiles. Specifically this section on it's [impact on build caching](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/impact-on-build-caching).

Comment: Looks promising. So I will define `ARG HEAD` in `Dockerfile`, precede `RUN git clone` by something like `RUN echo $HEAD`, and build with `docker build --build-arg HEAD=$(git ls-remote <repository> refs/heads/master | cut -f1)`.

Comment: Ye, that kind of thing is a pretty standard way of using the technique I guess.